# Asp.net logout codes not working

Tags: asp.net

it seems that when i hit log out button and hit the back button on the browser. it shows me the page which should not have been the case. I'm using form authentication and it works fine in Mozilla Firefox but not Google Chrome.

here is the codes.

```
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
```

how can i fix this.

Comment: if you are hitting back button then it will show you the page which is cached by browser. it will only refresh content if something is coming via AJAX. To avoid this place two redirections when user clicks logout internally. hence on clicking back button it will redirect to first redirected page which will again navigate to login.aspx.. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code with javascript to your logout button,

```
 btnLogout.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.clear(); return true;");
```

I believe that this will also clear the browser history, as JavaScript works on the client, and you are facing problem there only. It will not help with Server Side code.